# Syntax Error in trying to define a Tweepy API function

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to make a Twitter bot that selects a quote from a list of quotes I give it to Tweet every 2 hours. I keep having a syntax error when I try to define the Tweet daily function and I'm not exactly sure what's wrong. I'm a beginner in coding so if it's obvious, I apologize; it's my first time doing this. I already had success in having the app Tweet with the `api.update_status()` command but I'm not sure how to have select from the list I'm creating. I did import random, time, from `datetime`, `import datetime`, `timedelta` as well as `tweepy` and everything else successfully.

```
random.choices(tweets)
last_tweeted = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=2), random.choices(tweets)
tweets = ['insert, list, of tweets, I am adding']
```

**where python says I have a syntax code**

```
def tweet_daily(api, last_tweeted, random.choices(tweets):
     if last_tweeted < datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=2):
        logger.info(f"Tweeted {tweets, random.choices} at {datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S')}")
        return datetime.now()
    else:
        return last_tweeted

   api.update_status('tweets(random.choice)')`
```

Comment: I might have put this in weird but just let me know if I did ;; hope everyone can understand

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close parenthesis in the function definition:
`def tweet_daily(api, last_tweeted, random.choices(tweets):`